# Memcache intermittent errors

Tags: php, memcached

Any suggestions of the likely cause of the following intermittent Memcache connect failures would be appreciated:

```
Memcache::connect(): Server 127.0.0.1 (tcp 11211, udp 0) failed with: 
Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
```

As far as I can tell, the PHP scripts only attempt to open a connection when constructing a Controller i.e. there are no multiple attempts to open the connection. The error is reported in the one and only place a connection is attempted.

I have also taken a look at the memcached stats, which do not appear to be wrong:

```
array(36) {
  ["pid"]=> string(4) "5788"
  ["uptime"]=> string(6) "731274"
  ["time"]=> string(10) "1533137924"
  ["version"]=> string(16) "1.4.5_4_gaa7839e
  ["pointer_size"]=> string(2) "64"
  ["curr_connections"]=> string(1) "2"
  ["total_connections"]=> string(8) "31881420"
  ["connection_structures"]=> string(3) "163"
  ["cmd_get"]=> string(8) "26219501"
  ["cmd_set"]=> string(8) "17532714"
  ["cmd_flush"]=> string(4) "1110"
  ["get_hits"]=> string(8) "25834764"
  ["get_misses"]=> string(6) "384737"
  ["delete_misses"]=> string(1) "5"
  ["delete_hits"]=> string(7) "1252043"
  ["incr_misses"]=> string(1) "0"
  ["incr_hits"]=> string(1) "0"
  ["decr_misses"]=> string(1) "0"
  ["decr_hits"]=> string(1) "0"
  ["cas_misses"]=> string(1) "0"
  ["cas_hits"]=> string(1) "0"
  ["cas_badval"]=> string(1) "0"
  ["auth_cmds"]=> string(1) "0"
  ["auth_errors"]=> string(1) "0"
  ["bytes_read"]=> string(11) "12021422144"
  ["bytes_written"]=> string(12) "163830241155"
  ["limit_maxbytes"]=> string(10) "4294967296"
  ["accepting_conns"]=> string(1) "1"
  ["listen_disabled_num"]=> string(1) "0"
  ["threads"]=> string(1) "4"
  ["conn_yields"]=> string(1) "0"
  ["bytes"]=> string(8) "89537575"
  ["curr_items"]=> string(5) "15811"
  ["total_items"]=> string(7) "2871704"
  ["evictions"]=> string(1) "0"
  ["reclaimed"]=> string(6) "570282"
}
```

System is running on Windows Server if that affects things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](https://support.socketlabs.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/61)  appears to resolve the problem.

> It means that you are exhausting all the available network ports on
>   the machine. By default the OS only has around 4000 ports available
>   that are not reserved by the system. What happens is that when any
>   network connection is closed it goes into a TIME_WAIT state for 240
>   seconds and cannot be reused until this wait state is over. So as an
>   example, if there are 16 connections per second for 4 minutes
>   (16*4*60=3840), you will exhaust all the ports shortly there after.
>   Now if you have HAS and the MTA on the same machine, this will get
>   exhausted a lot sooner because in addition to them communicating with
>   each other, which uses 2 ports (one for the MTA and one for HAS), the
>   MTA uses up a lot of ports sending the mail.

The solution is as follows:

> You can fix this by modifying the below values.
>
> 1. One of the ways is to increase the dynamic port range. The max by default is 5000. You can set this up to 65534. 
>      `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\MaxUserPort` is
>      the key to use.
> 2. The second thing you can do is, once the connection does get into an TIME_WAIT state, you can reduce the time it is in that state.
>      Default is 4 minutes, but you can set this to 30 seconds.
>      `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\TCPTimedWaitDelay`
>      is the key to use.
>
> After these changes are made the system must be restarted.

In the event this fails, try using **resmon** (a little known Windows Resource monitor) to check your port usage for conflicting services. You can access it from the Cortana search box or a command shell...

(I'd like to claim credit for this, but it was a team effort!)

Finally, when you connect with **Memcache**, it is useful to check your connection has been successful with the return from the `connect` method. You may have to adopt a different approach if using `Memcache::add_server` as this method will only find a connection has failed on the first attempt to access memcache.